# Tinymce force linebreaks when it appears '\n'

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, tinymce, textarea

I'm trying to populate a `textarea` encapsuled inside a TinyMCE text editor. The problem is that when I get a string which contains `\n` because the texte is displayed in only one line. I tried many parameters inside the init function but it doesn't work. Here's my javascript :

```
    tinymce.init({
          selector: 'textarea',
          apply_source_formatting : true,
          remove_linebreaks : false,  
          height: 500,
          width: 800,
          menubar: false,
          plugins: [
            'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor textcolor',
            'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
            'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code help autoresize textcolor'
          ],
          toolbar: 'insert | undo redo |  styleselect | bold italic backcolor forecolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help'
        });
```

Any suggeestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting the rendered HTML to have a line break in it when you look at it in TinyMCE or are you wanting the code view to show the line break?

If you want the line break in the rendered HTML you will have to convert the `\n` to a `<br>` as the browser won't render a `\n` visually as a line break in HTML.